# Usb not accessible because of I/O device error

Tags: windows, io, usb

Hi I have a 32G toshiba usb that is very important to me. every time when I try to access it I get this message "***The request could not performed because of an I/O devices error***" I searched on google to find the solution and the most appearing solution was to run this command "**chkdsk /f m:**".....*m being the name of the drive*. I tried this but i get message "**Cannot open volume for direct access**"

Answer (score 1):

This is very likely a software error like i.e. a *corrupted partition table* or a locking of the device  by an application (firewall,...) not necessarily a hardware error.

In most cases this is a corrupted partition table (device not removed safely,...)

There is a tool called **TestDisk** that repairs corrupted partition tables
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

For data recovery see i.e. **PhotoRec** http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

More information is in http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/storage/how-fix-unrecognized-usb-drive-3513573

(http://www.ccm.net/forum/affich-396310-unable-to-format-or-open-usb uses device manager)

If this is all not working then it is very likely a hardware error. To verify this get **USBView** (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560019(v=vs.85).aspx). Try if you can see the stick with it. If USBView can not see the stick at all it is a hardware error because then even the most basic USB protocol communication is not working